Windows 10 not context switching on std::this_thread::yield
I have the following C++ code (greatly simplified):
void MyClass::do()
{
  {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
    while (!done)
    {
      ...
    }
  }
  std::this_thread::yield();
}

This function is called simultaneously from multiple threads, and within those threads, it is called in a loop.
What I would have expected (and what I see on Ubuntu) is that when I reach the yield() in one thread, if the other thread is stopped at the mutex, context switching happens and I essentially go back and forth between the two threads until one of them completes.
What I see on Windows 10 is that the first thread completes (or runs the multiple iterations) before the second thread gets a chance.  If I replace the yield() with sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1)), I get the results I would have expected.
It seems what is happening is that the yield() does not context switch to a thread that is stopped at a mutex - even if the mutex is now unlocked.
Does anyone understand what is going on here, and how to solve this without having to add sleeps to my code?

std::this_thread::yield() is only a hint and it's effect is implementation defined.

Windows kernel does the scheduling, when a thread yields its time-slice and there is no other thread waiting, the same thread gets the time-slice back. Perhaps that's what you are observing.

if there are no other threads at the same priority, yield has no effect https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/yield

Suppose your thread R has just Released mtx, while your thread W was Waiting for mtx. Now, thread R calls yield().

Does yield do anything at all? It is not required to do anything at all. Whether or not it does something depends on the OS that is running your program and/or the std:: library that is linked with your program. The authors of the OS and the library are not required to tell you what they decided it should do.

Suppose that yield is non-trivial. In that case, it must wake a thread that is ready-to-run. Is your thread W ready to run by the time your thread R enters the yield() call? Maybe it is, and maybe it isn't. You don't have any way to know. The answer could depend again on the OS architecture, and/or on the library architecture, and/or on a roll of the dice.

Suppose that your thread W is, in fact, ready-to-run before thread R enters yield(). Is thread W the one that the OS will choose to replace thread R? Maybe it will be, maybe it won't. What other threads* are ready-to-run on your host? How long have they been waiting? What are their priorities? What scheduling policy (or policies) will govern the choice? Once again, it's going to be hard to know.


The moral of the story is, use yield in the way it was intended. Use it to mark "good" places for your program to yield its current time slice, but don't depend on it to do anything at all.

Update:

Is your program running on a multi-CPU host? and was one or more of its CPUs idle? If so, then the yield need not end the time slice, because the scheduler may already have chosen to "wake up" thread W on a currently idle processor. But in that case...

...Suppose thread A comes around the outermost loop, and back to the point where it locks mtx again before thread W manages to fully "wake up" and grab mtx for itself. That's another possibility.

*Don't forget all of the threads that may belong to various OS services and,  if it's Linux, don't forget the kernel threads.
